# Shutdown sagemaker instance at night using cdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, amazon-sagemaker

I have been using sagemaker recently and am using inference with GPU-based instances.

I am thinking of turning off sagemaker inference instances at night—for example, 8 pm to 8 am.
I want to do that using cdk. Not sure if it is a crazy idea or not?

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon SageMaker supports different inference options that fits various use cases. You can use [SageMaker Asynchronous endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/async-inference.html) to save cost during idle time (after operational hours), you don't have to use AWS CDK/ AWS CloudFormation while using this option.

Amazon SageMaker supports automatic scaling (autoscaling) your asynchronous endpoint. Autoscaling dynamically adjusts the number of instances provisioned for a model in response to changes in your workload. Unlike other hosted models Amazon SageMaker supports, with Asynchronous Inference you can also scale down your asynchronous endpoints instances to zero. Requests that are received when there are zero instances are queued for processing once the endpoint scales up.

Refer [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/async-inference.html), [samples](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/main/async-inference) and [blogs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/run-computer-vision-inference-on-large-videos-with-amazon-sagemaker-asynchronous-endpoints/) here.